# Different view on live server and other browsers

Tags: css

I've worked on a mobile version of my school project in Visual Studio and the live server window. Now when I open up my project in Safari or Chrome I can't see pictures and all content has changed in size.

Any thoughts on why this occurred and what is the best way to fix this?

[This is what it looks like on the live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFC2M.png)

[This is what it looks like in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntrde.png)

*(Can add that this is the first time I'm working on a project, so if my code is not the best, you know why)*

```
html {
  background-image: url(/background.jpg);
  background-size: 800%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

header { 
  background-color: white;
  height: 30px;
  width: 212px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hamburger div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(65, 211, 155);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1 {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgb(163, 163, 163);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;  
}

nav {
  display: none;
}

nav a {
  color:rgb(65, 211, 155);
  text-decoration: none;
}

#mainphoto {  
  width: 180px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

img {
  width: 160px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block; 
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 370px;
  width: 212px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

section a:link {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section a:hover {
  color: rgb(65, 211, 155);
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card{
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 255px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.card a:link {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.card a:hover {
  color: rgb(65, 211, 155);
}

.card a:visited {
  color: grey;
}
´´´
```

Comment: Check your browser's dev tools. Specifically errors in the console and network tabs

Comment: Can you please share a screenshots of the different results you are getting ?

Comment: @SARANSURYA please see my original post, there are links to screenshots attached there

Comment: You need to move your files along with the project.
The website is missing the stylesheets (css) and the images. Thats why its not working.

Comment: I did not have my images in the image folder so seems like that gave them error. I moved them and fixed the images. I'll change the code to make the content fit the browser view and not live server.

Comment: Hey there, Could you please share your HTML so we can make sense of your CSS. also I noticed an error   `background-image: url(/background.jpg);` the URL or path should be inside `"double quote "` or `'single quote' `. Also in your case, I think your CSS file path is wrong because changes are not even applying that's what I could tell from your images.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same problem. Solved it. Here's how- 
The reason it is running on live server but not on other static platforms/browsers is because you have written the path of images wrong.
Although VS Code's live server successfully runs when in CSS files, you declare path according to this syntax: `background-image: url(/background.jpg);`, it is illegal and incomprehensive for most browsers. Instead use this syntax of path declaration: `background-image: url(../background.jpg);`. *(Notice the difference? There are 2 dots to reach current directory first)*

Also, if you are declaring images in HTML file with this syntax: `<img src="/current_directory/time.png">`, it would again disappear in the browser. Instead, *(a)use 2 dots to denote current directory and (b)use backslash instead of slash*. Like this: `<img src="..\current_directory\time.png">`